# Reading an RSS feed

Tags: kotlin, rss, adt

How can I read data from an RSS feed using jsoup in kotlin? I have to create an ADT containing a list of items and general attributes such as title,  link,  description,  pubDate and in the end I have to print the title and the link for every item.

Comment: "using jsoup" — don't. That's an HTML parser. Find an RSS parser instead.

Comment: it is required to use jsoup by teacher..

Comment: Then ask **them** how to use a wildly inappropriate tool for the job since it is their requirement.